# How to display one number after another in the browser

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to create some code that will display random numbers one after another with a 1.5 second gap between number changes. I have tried this about a million different ways at this point and none work. I'm very discouraged because I have been learning code for a few months now and thought I had mastered the simple stuff like this. Anyway, here is the code:

```
var javascriptElement = "numbers-display";
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

//This function takes a single argument and displays it in the browser.
function displayContent (content) {
  document.getElementById(javascriptElement).innerHTML = content;
};

function runRandomNumbers (array) {
  displayContent(array[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)]);
};

function runOnInterval(content) {
  setInterval(content, 1500);
};

runOnInterval(runRandomNumbers(numbers));
```

Is anyone able to tell me what is wrong with this? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)** requires a function ***reference*** to be passed to it, not statements.

As the JavaScript compiler first reads in the code, the statement `runRandomNumbers(numbers)` is executed immediately (so you get one random number generated and printed to the screen) and then, the return value from it (which is `undefined`) is what is actually being passed and stored as the callback to the timer. When the timer hits its interval there is nothing (`undefined`) to call, so the function runs once and you see one number, but then that's it.

The solution is to wrap the code you want executed at regular intervals in a function so that that function reference can be passed to `.setInterval()`.

Additionally, if you want to show a list of the generated numbers, you need to set the contents of the element with `+=` if you want to keep the old value and just concatenate on to it.

NOTES:

- You have a lot of separation in your functions, which really doesn't
  add any value to the code and, instead makes it more difficult to
  follow.
- Only use `.innerHTML` when the string you are setting/getting
  contains HTML because it forces the browser to parse the string for
  HTML, which is a waste of resources, when there isn't any HTML.
  Instead, use `.textContent` for getting/setting strings that don't
  include any HTML.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("numbers-display");
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

//This function takes a single argument and displays it in the browser.
function runRandomNumbers (array) {
    element.textContent += array[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)];
}

// A function is expected as the argument here. That function
// will be stored as the callback for the timer.
function runOnInterval(callbackFunction) {
  setInterval(callbackFunction, 1500);
}

// We'll pass a function as the datat for the argument
runOnInterval(function(){ runRandomNumbers(numbers) });
```

```html
<div id="numbers-display"></div>
```

Comment: Great answer, it explains in detail what is not working.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the function `runRandomNumbers` to `runOnInterval()`, not its returned value `runRandomNumbers(numbers)`. See code below:

```js
var javascriptElement = "numbers-display";
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

//This function takes a single argument and displays it in the browser.
function displayContent (content) {
  document.getElementById(javascriptElement).innerHTML = content;
};

function runRandomNumbers (array) {
  displayContent(array[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)]);
};

function runOnInterval(fn, numbers) {
  setInterval(function() { fn(numbers) }, 1500);
};

runOnInterval(runRandomNumbers, numbers);
```

```html
<div id="numbers-display"></div>
```

Also, I have changed `runOnInterval` so that it accepts the function and the array of numbers as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` expects an (callback-)function it should call. Thus the function-name or an anonymous function.

Either

```
function doEverySecondAndHalf() {
    runRandomNumbers(numbers);
}
runOnInterval(doEverySecondAndHalf); // Note the missing () after doEverySecondAndHalf
```

Or

```
runOnInterval(function() {
    runRandomNumbers(numbers);
});
```